# Size of a path defined on a Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let $G=(V,E)$ (Such that $\vert V\vert$) be a Hamiltonian cubic graph and $v\in V$. We represent a graph as a cycle with vertices labeled in such a way that $(0,\ldots ,n-1)$ is a Hamiltonian cycle and a set of edges between non-successive vertices of a cycle. Then let us define $L$ as a set of successive vertices in Ham. cycle labeled $v,v+1,\ldots,v-k-1$, where $\vert V \vert \ge k \ge 2$ (we consider every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ mod n).

Then my question is the following: why the size of $L$ is always $\vert V \vert -k$? And why any vertex of $L$ has at least two neighbors in $L$?

Comment: What is $P$? What is $i$? What is $k$ (you define it as some vertex first, and later it is an integer)? I assume $n$ is the number of vertices.

Comment: Now it should be more clear I did some mistakes

Comment: $|L|=|V|-k$ because the only vertices not in $L$ are the vertices labelled from $v-k$ up to $v-1$, which are $k$ vertices. As for the second question, I don't see why the end vertices (labelled $v$ and $v-k-1$) would necessarily have two neighbours in $L$. Even with a cubic graph, those end vertices might have two of their neighbours in the missing range $v-k$ to $v-1$, leaving only one neighbour in $L$.